Calculate the propagated uncertainty by measurement error in linear fit coefficients
I am currently taking a physic experiment class and am required to analyse the uncertainty of data caused by measurement error. They have provided me the standard way to propagate the error, namely by using partial deriviatives. However, some of the final datas can only be calculated via calculating the slope and interception of a linear fit of data. Though I am able to perform that easily in mathematica, the confident interval functions in mathematica do not provide an option for me to enter the measurement error in a linear fit model, and I am stuck. Is there a lib or package in Python/Mathematica/Matlab that can calculate the uncertainty of measurement propagated in linear fit coefficient?
Besides, I am just a freshman, so please do not provide me with too many statistics formulas since I do not have the mathematical background to understand them :(

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
